# How to open aspx page inside bootstrap modal popup

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog, window

I have this link

```
<a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalC'>Book Now</a>
```

And i have this code which opens a bootstrap modal popup.

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalC" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cantidad reservas mensuales</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="content">

      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Everything appearing inside div with id content is what appears inside modal popup, so my question is is there a way to show my already created aspx webform inside the modal popup without having to copy all the html and codebehind to this div?

I've heard something about window.open but i think it is not the case, Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm working on updating a legacy app without changing it from webforms and had the same question. Copying all the code from one file to another sounded like a mess. I'm glad someone else had the same question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `iframe` into the modal body and load the url of your page inside it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalC" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cantidad reservas mensuales</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="content">
                <iframe src="your new page url">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want to load the page everytime you open the modal, you can add the `iframe src` when you click on the button you use to open the modal (or whichever method you use to open it).

Comment: unfurtanely, it does not work for some reason , the bootstrap calendar stops working and so does the modal popup.

Comment: My mistake, the modal-body should be inside modal-content. Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help you:
Add jquery and bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            initializeEvents();
        });

var initializeEvents = function () {
        $("#btnCarga").click(function () {
           //agregas el aspx que quieres mostrar, el titulo y el pie de página pueden ser opcionales
            ShowModalIframe('OtherPage.aspx', 'Tittle', 'Footer');
        });
    };
//Crea un modal con un iframe en el contenido donde se mostrará el aspx
var ShowModalIframe = function (uriContent, tittle = 'Titulo', footer='Carga completada') {

        var html = '<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">\
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">\
                        <div class="modal-content">\
                            <div class="modal-header">\
                                <h5 class="modal-title">'+tittle+'</h5>\
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">\
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>\
                                </button>\
                              </div>\
                            <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">\
                                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">\
                                  <iframe id="iframe-modal" class="embed-responsive-item" src="'+document.location.origin+'/'+uriContent+'"></iframe>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="modal-footer">\
                                '+footer+'\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>';

        var dialog = $(html);
        dialog.modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnCarga" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
  Mostrar modal
</button>
```